# LINQ to SQL execute method on select

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

Im really new to LINQ so I'm trying to figure out how to execute method with lambda expressions.

```
   public void GetData()
    {

     using (MyClassesDataContext context = new MyClassesDataContext())
                {
                    var problems = (from p in context.Problems select p).Take(10);
                    problems.Select(t => DisplayData(t.Text));
                }

    }

     public void DisplayData(string Text)
            { 

            }
```

I'm getting this error:

> The type arguments for method
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
>   System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage.
>   Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

at this line:

```
 problems.Select(t => DisplayData(t.Text));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `DisplayData` is void. It should return something. Or something like `problem.ToList().ForEach(t => DisplayData(t.Text))`

Comment: Problems is SQL Table that I just draged from Server explorer and created to MyClassesDataContext(I'm not sure what do you mean by definition)

Comment: Thanks, problem.ToList().ForEach(t => DisplayData(t.Text)) will do!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Select` operator is used to create a projection - i.e. the lambda expression passed as an argument instructs how to create *new object* out of each object in the collection.

What you want to do is, instead, to perform an action on each item from the collection. Use `foreach` loop for that:

```
var problems = (from p in context.Problems select p).Take(10);

foreach (var t in problems)
{
     DisplayData(t.Text);
}
```

Comment: You should do the projection first: .Take(10).Select(x => x.Text); This will help to fetch less data.

Comment: DisplayData will acutally use all the fields from t, not just Text. I wanted to do this but didn't know how to use anonymus type in standard forech loop, it's so easy. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you make the following change to your code, it will work fine:

```
problems.Select(t => { DisplayData(t.Text); return true; })
```

Answer (score -1):

> ***Parallel.ForEach***. Here is a sample example...

**[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx)**  - Executes a foreach operation in which iterations may run in parallel.

---

### Sample Class

```
class abc
{
    public int i;
}
```

---

### Sample LINQ Code

```
List<abc> d = new List<abc>();
d.Add(new abc { i = 1 });
d.Add(new abc() { i = 2 });
d.Add(new abc() { i = 3 });
d.Add(new abc() { i = 4 });

var problems = (from p in d select p).Take(2);
int k = 0;
System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(problems, j =>
    {
        abcd(ref j.i);
        k += j.i;
    }
);
```

---

### Sample Function

```
void abcd(ref int i)
{
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Are there any advatages of using Parallel ForEach for only 10 Items?

Comment: hmmm, Yes. It's a parallel processing loop. This means virtual multiple threads. It's a matter of 10 records and case may arrise where it may need to append zero(s) in your present requirement...and it is good to execute parallely 10 records as well.